# How to get the oracle dataguard log transfer and applying status?

Tags: oracle, dataguard

Logs are transferred from primary db instanes to stand-by db and applied continuously.

Please advise how to get the report in the following format in browser at some frequency(say 5sec/10sec) for monitoring purposes at stand-by db(prefer to any built-in function or class in oracle dataguard):

`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`log_name   instance   created_time   tx_start    tx_end  tx_duration  tx_success   apply_start    apply_end   apply_duration apply_success`

`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`...`

`...`

`...`

`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the V$RECOVERY.... views (e.g. look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-RECOVER_FILE.html#GUID-E06FD908-5BFC-4280-8808-3A8D85115262) and the following views). They have lots of info on recovery processes and stats.

Answer (score 0):

`v$managed_standby` is very usefully to check the DG status.